# Performance of mass insert to Oracle database via OJDBC

Tags: java, performance, oracle, ojdbc

I have a Java program that is used to insert a lot (750.000) of records in an Oracle database. I am using the OJDBC6 library, with the OCI client. The table to be written to contains 330 columns, of which 8 appear in one or more indexes.

After having tried two approaches, I'm still struggling with some performance issues.

1. Creating a prepared statement once, filling the parameters for each record and thereafter executing the statement takes 1h29.
2. Creating a prepared statement once, filling the parameters for each record, adding them to a batch and executing the batch every 500/1000/5000 (I tried several options) processed records takes 0h27.

However, when the same data is mapped to the same tables using an ETL tool like Informatica PowerCenter, it only takes a couple of minutes. I understand that it might be wishful thinking to reach this timings, but I doubt whether no performance can be gained.

Does anyone has an idea about reasonable timings for this action, and how they can be achieved? Any help is appreciated, many thanks in advance!

(A related question: I will have to update a lot of records, too. What would be the most efficient approach: either keeping track of the columns that were changed and creating a record-dependent prepared statement containing only these columns; or always updating all columns, thereby reusing the same prepared statement?)

Comment: You could insert the data in unindex temporary table from which you do insert into with select. If you have only single writer at a time, you can use multiple threads and use normal table as staging area. You could also experiment parallel batched inserts directly to the target table, if you do not require everything to be committed in a single transaction

Comment: Btw having table with 330 columns is not usually a very good idea

Comment: Is [auto-commit on](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#disable_auto_commit)? Not sure how that works under the hood but I can imagine it would slow things down a bit.

Comment: Do some of these fields contain large data (blobs, clobs)? That could cause problems. In the past I have, using the batched api, inserted 10K records a minute. Not 330 columns each, but 80/90 columns.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback.
@SamiKorhonen: the layout of the table is implied by the vendor of an external tool. Nothing we can do about that, unfortunately. I will take the parallel hint into account.

Comment: @AlexPoole: thanks, that had quite some impact. Now playing around with the commit interval somehow to find an ideal trade-off.

Comment: @Zagrev: no large data. Only strings, dates and float values.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try would be dropping the indexes, inserting the data, then reloading the indexes. Not as easy from Java, but simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ThreadGroup on Java 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html

;)